Rolling in opposite direction to linear motion
In this blog about a cylinder rolling up a frictionless incline, the author concludes that the cylinder will still be spinning clockwise at the top of its ascent up the hill and will then descend with the spin in the opposite direction to that required for rolling without slipping. My question is what happens when the cylinder arrives at the bottom of the slope and makes contact with the horizontal surface that does have a non zero coefficient of friction? Will the cylinder immediately try to roll back up the hill, or will it continue to the left for a while and come to a stop or will it just slow down until the rotation reverses and then settle down to rolling without slipping to the left?
P.S. This question might seem similar to to this question: paradoxic cylinder rolling in opposite direction, but that question is about accelerating a cylinder from rest by applying a constant horizontal accelerating force whereas this question is about a cylinder free rolling without any external horizontal force being applied.

If there is no friction then there is no torque to change the direction of spin.

@JohnAlexiou There is friction on the horizontal surface, once the cylinder has slid back down the ramp backwards. I am asking what happens then.

System: Object of radius $r$, mass $m$, and moment of inertia about centre of mass $I$.
On entering the horizontal region where there is friction the velocity of the object away from the incline is $v_0$ and its angular velocity is $\omega_0$ in the opposite direction to which it needs to be when it is rolling without slipping.
A horizontal frictional force $\mu mg$ acts towards the slope and this applies a torque about the centre of mass of the object $\mu mgr$.
Thus the linear acceleration is $\mu g$ and the angular acceleration is $d\frac{\mu m g r}{I}$.
As the accelerations are constant the equations of motion are, linear velocity $v= v_0-\mu g t$, and angular velocity $\omega = -\omega_0+ \dfrac{\mu m g r}{I} t$ where $t$ is the time.
The no slipping condition is $v=r \omega$ at time $T$.
This can be displayed graphically as follows.

Solutions can be found for a solid cylinder ($I=\frac 12 mr^2$) and for a sphere ($I=\frac 25 m r^2$).
The extremes are a cylindrical shell with $I+mr^2$ (left-hand graph) when the cylindrical shell stops and when the mass is concentrated near the centre of gravity with $I\ll mr^2$ (right-hand graph) when the final linear speed of the object tends to $v_0$.


Could you clarify. Initially the cylinder is translating to the the left with $v_0$ and rotating in the wrong direction  and the friction is sliding friction $\mu mg$ due the difference in velocity between the cylinder contact patch and the surface. Once the cylinder angular velocity slows down to the the correct rotation rate for the rolling without slipping condition, the friction becomes rolling friction which is significantly less than sliding friction, so the downward slope of the velocity line is less steep after time T on the graph?

and the graph for $r\omega$ stops increasing and becomes also becomes almost horizontal (constant) after time T too?

@KDP - Sorry, I did not terminate the right-hand graph correctly. After the intersection (no slipping) both graphs are horizontal starting at the intersection and the static frictional force is zero. I have assumed that rolling friction is zero. Thanks for pointing my error out and I have corrected the graph.

This really depends on several factors: The angular momentum of the cylinder about its axis, its linear momentum due to sliding down the surface, and the coefficient of friction. If its angular momentum and the coefficient of friction are both sufficiently large compared to its linear momentum, it will slide for a short while until all the kinetic energy from the linear motion has dissipated into heat, and then roll towards the incline again. If the angular momentum is small compared to the linear momentum and the coefficient of friction, it will slip until all the rotational kinetic energy has dissipated, and then roll away from the incline in the usual fashion. If the coefficient of friction is small compared to the momenta, it will slide along the horizontal surface while spinning, until the entire kinetic energy has dissipated. Of course, there are equilibrium cases in between these.
Edit: For a cylinder with radius $r$ and mass $m$, rolling without slipping with angular velocity $\omega$, the linear momentum always equals $p = mr\omega$, while the angular momentum is $L = mr^2\omega/2$. The ratio between angular and linear momentum is therefore:
$$
\frac{L}{p} = \frac{r}{2}
$$
So that it really comes down to the ratio between the radius of the cylinder and the friction coefficient.

Doesn't the initial condition of the cylinder rolling towards the slope on the horizontal surface ,without slipping, put a constraint on the relationship between the angular and linear momentum?

That is true, i added to my answer to consider this.

If the angular momentum is small compared to the linear momentum and the coefficient of friction $\dots$.  Except right at the end, you are comparing "apples" (linear momentum) to "oranges" (angular momentum).  The same with If the coefficient of friction is small compared to the momenta, $\dots$

Instead of going up a ramp and then back down with reversed speed, it is exactly the same as if the ball hit a frictionless wall. Imagine a very steep ramp, where the ball rides up and down quickly. At the limit, make the ramp vertical.
After the impact, the speed of the center of mass reverses direction.
So now we have one instant where the motion of the ball _is not compatible with the no-slip condition at the point of contact with the floor. This is a similar situation to a bowling ball when it first contacts the ground.
For as long as the no-slip condition is violated there will be a torque produced by the frictional force which will gradually reverse the spin to match the speed of the center of mass. But at the same time the center of mass will slow down due to this frictional force.
if you plot the rotation vs. speed of center of mass on a graph you see it follows the following trajectory

After the ramp, the angle $\theta$ at which rotation is changed as a function of change in speed is found by
$$ \tan \theta = \frac{ m r^2}{I} $$
where $m$ is the mass, $r$ is the radius and $I = \tfrac{2}{5} m r^2$ the mass moment of inertia of a solid sphere. This means for a solid sphere the angle is $\theta \approx 68.2°$ which means the speed is going to not going to flip and the ball will continue moving aways from the ramp.
